# Auto order appendices

Tags: appendices

I am wondering if it is possible to automatically order my appendices (just like my references with bibtex), so I won't have to change it all the time if a reference in my text changes. For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

Hi, this is a document to ask a question about appendix references and auto updating them.

For example, first I referred to appendix "\,Example 1"\, here, by using \ref{appendix:1} 
and after that, I used the reference for appendix \ref{appendix:2}.


\newpage
\begin{appendices}

\section{Example 1}
\label{appendix:1}
\newpage

\section{Example 2}
\label{appendix:2}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

That is my current code, however I want to be able to refer to an appendix without the need to change it, just like I do using Bibtex for my references. So when I change it to:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

Hi, this is a document to ask a question about appendix references and auto updating them.

Now I refer to to appendix "\,Example 2"\, first, by using \ref{appendix:2} 
and after that, I used the reference for appendix \ref{appendix:1}.


\newpage
\begin{appendices}

\section{Example 1}
\label{appendix:1}
\newpage

\section{Example 2}
\label{appendix:2}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

However, this does not automatically update appendix B to A and vice versa. Does anyone know a way, perhaps something simular to Bibtex but for appendices, that I can use? I hope the question is clear, feel free to ask if I forgot something.

Comment: So you want the appendices to be created in the order in which they appear in the text, sort of like floats and endfloat?

Comment: Yes exactly, just like my references using Bibtex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses endfloat to move the examples from the body to the appendices.  The advantage is that it saves the text to another file (.eee) instead of taking up RAM.  The main disadvantage is that examples can only be one page long.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[nolists,nomarkers,nofigures,notables]{endfloat}

\newenvironment{example}[1]% #1 = label
{\minipage[t][0.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}%
  \section{Example \arabic{section}}\label{#1}}
{\endminipage}%\oldendexample}

\DeclareDelayedFloat{example}[eee]{List of Examples}

\begin{document}

Hi, this is a document to ask a question about appendix references and auto updating them.

For example, first I referred to appendix "\,Example 1"\, here, by using \ref{appendix:1} 
\begin{example}{appendix:1}
  First example
\end{example}
and after that, I used the reference for appendix \ref{appendix:2}.
\begin{example}{appendix:2}
  Second example
\end{example}


\newpage
\begin{appendices}
\processdelayedfloats
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

---

This solution saves the examples as macros.  Its advantage is that it is much more adaptable than endfloat.  Its main disadvantage is that the contents have to be expanded immediately.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcounter{example}
\NewEnviron{example}[1]% #1 = label
{\stepcounter{example}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname examplelabel.\arabic{example}\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname example.\arabic{example}\endcsname{\BODY}%
}

\newcommand{\ProcessExamples}{\bgroup
  \count1=0
  \loop\ifnum\count1 < \value{example}\relax
    \advance\count1 by 1
    \section{Example \number\count1}%
    \label{\csname examplelabel.\number\count1\endcsname}%
    \csname example.\number\count1\endcsname
    \newpage
  \repeat
\egroup}


\begin{document}

Hi, this is a document to ask a question about appendix references and auto updating them.

For example, first I referred to appendix "\,Example 1"\, here, by using \ref{appendix:1} 
\begin{example}{appendix:1}
  First example
\end{example}
and after that, I used the reference for appendix \ref{appendix:2}.
\begin{example}{appendix:2}
  Second example
\end{example}

\newpage
\begin{appendices}
\ProcessExamples
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```