# Making an ordered appendix

Tags: appendices

I am trying to make it so I can, at any point in the body of my document, include a reference that becomes part of an annex.

I have based it loosely on this: [Auto order appendices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452596/auto-order-appendices)

```latex
\newcounter{annexes}
\newcommand{\annexRef}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{annex~\ref*{#1}} %
\stepcounter{annexes}%
\expandafter\xdef\csname annexpath.\arabic{annexes}\endcsname{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\printAnnexes}{
    \appendix
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
    \begin{appendices}
        \count1=0
        \loop\ifnum\count1 < \value{annexes}\relax
            \advance\count1 by 1\relax
            {
            \count2=1 \relax
            \count3=0 \relax
            \loop\ifnum\count2 < \count1 \relax
                \expandafter\ifx\csname annexpath.\number\count1\endcsname = \csname annexpath.\number\count2\endcsname
                    \advance\count3 by 1 \relax
                \fi
                \advance\count2 by 1 \relax
            \repeat
            \ifnum\count3 < 1 \relax
                \input{\csname annexpath.\number\count1\endcsname}
            \fi
            }
        \repeat
    \end{appendices}
}
```

So, anywhere in my document, I can write `\annexRef{path/to/file.latex}` and it creates a reference and includes it in the annex section.

It currently inputs the annex file correctly, however the inner loop and subsequent `\ifnum` is supposed to make the file is only input once. I.e., if the same file is referenced twice, it is currently being input twice, I only want it to be input once.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `expl3` it's not difficult. The idea is to store the list of references in a sequence, but only if the item is not yet in.

At the end we can map the sequence and create the appendices.

Here I use `filecontents` and `\jobname` just to make the example self-contained.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-annex-1}
This is annex 1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-annex-2}
This is annex 2
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-annex-3}
This is annex 3
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\annexRef}{m}
 {
  \joanthan_annex_ref:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printAnnexes}{}
 {
  \joanthan_annex_print:
 }

\seq_new:N \g_joanthan_annex_list_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \joanthan_annex_ref:n
 {
  \hyperref[#1]{annex\nobreakspace\ref*{#1}}
  \seq_if_in:NnF \g_joanthan_annex_list_seq { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_joanthan_annex_list_seq { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \joanthan_annex_print:
 {
  \appendix
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_joanthan_annex_list_seq
   {
    \section{Annex~\ref*{##1}\label{##1}}
    \input{##1}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{First}

Some text \annexRef{\jobname-annex-1}

Some text \annexRef{\jobname-annex-3}

\section{Second}

Some text \annexRef{\jobname-annex-1}

Some text \annexRef{\jobname-annex-2}

\printAnnexes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly - I have not come across the expl3 before. I've marked you answer as accepted because it works, although I would still be interested to know why my original code didn't. I have been using latex basically for a while, but am still trying to learn some of the more complex aspects.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your original code work, replace the outer loop with this one:

```tex
\count1=0
\loop\ifnum\count1 < \value{annexes}\relax
    \advance\count1 by 1\relax
    % only input the annex if it is known
    \ifcsname we have already seen \csname annexpath.\the\count1\endcsname\endcsname
    \else \input{\csname annexpath.\the\count1\endcsname}\fi
    % the line below leaves the csname defined (and equivalent to \relax)
    \csname we have already seen \csname annexpath.\the\count1\endcsname\endcsname
\repeat
```

Here is the why and how:

- TeX programming that involves counters is awkward and verbose, hard to read and hard to write. So while in other programming languages, numeric variables may be the first thing you reach for, you should try and avoid them in TeX.
- A wonderful and idiomatic tool, on the other hand, is defining macros. Effectively, macro definition can give you associative arrays – and maybe you should indeed think of macros as arrays instead of procedures.

  - As you already know, any character can be part of a macro name by means of `\csname ... \endcsname`.
  - The existence of a macro can be tested with `\ifdefined` or with `\ifcsname ... \endcsname`.
  - A simple `\csname ... \endcsname` statement will give a non-existing macro the meaning of `\relax`.
- So if you simply define a macro for every file you have already read (that is: add its filename as a key to the array `we have already seen`), you only need check its presence in that array (that is: existence as a macro) before reading.

In fact, you can simplify your code even further and use no counter at all:

```tex
\newtoks\annexToks
\def\annexRef#1{%
    % store the file names in a list
    \global\annexToks =
        \expandafter{\the\annexToks{#1}}%
    \hyperref[#1]{annex-\ref*{#1}}}

\def\printAnnexes{%
    \appendix
    % terminate the list with the command that iterates over the list
    \expandafter\doPrintAnnexes
        \the\annexToks{\doPrintAnnexes}}
\def\doPrintAnnexes#1{%
    \ifx\doPrintAnnexes#1
        \expandafter\gobble % eats the continuing \doPrintAnnexes
    \else
        \ifcsname we have seen #1\endcsname
        \else
            \section {Annex #1}
            \label {#1}
            \input {#1}
        \fi
        \csname we have seen #1\endcsname
    \fi \doPrintAnnexes}

\def\gobble#1{} % you could also use \@gobble if the at is a letter
```

Here, you store the files you (might) want to read in a list, as `{}`-surrounded groups in the token register `\annexToks`. The construction with `\doPrintAnnexes` gives you the easiest way of looping through such a list.